# Why doesn't AwesomeWM recognize all of my modkey keypresses when using an external keyboard or how can I fix it?

Tags: keyboard, awesome

I'm using awesome v3.5.6 on a ThinkPad Edge e440 with a mostly stock configuration in awesome (titlebars enabled, some layouts omitted, and the taglist omitted from the wibox). I have a Logitech G110 keyboard connected directly to the laptop's USB port.

modkey is still default at Mod4.

Everything works correctly using the laptop's built-in keyboard.

Using the external keyboard, Awesome doesn't recognize that my modkey is pressed when used in combination with other keypresses, such as modkey+enter to open terminal or modkey+r to open the run box.

Using the external keyboard, AwesomeWM does recognize that I'm pressing modkey when I click on a titlebar, such as to resize or move the window.

I do use QuickSynergy, and the problem exists with and without it.

I have used the same keyboard on desktop computers with earlier versions of awesome and it worked correctly in those setups.

xev does not respond when i press my mod4, and it shows no KeyPress or KeyRelease event. yet I can resize the xev window by holding down mod4, right clicking the titlebar, and then moving the mouse. xev does not output a KeyPress event when I do this.

I've spent some time researching it, and I'd really like to know a workaround or a solution, short of those I'm interested in understanding why so that I can seek a solution on my own or elsewhere.

Comment: Curious problem. Did you try `xev` to check that your external keyboard is sending the appropriate KeyCodes ? BTW, I am using AwesomeWM 3.5.6 with a TP X230 and internal/external keyboards without any problem.

Comment: sincere thank you for replying. good question. xev does not respond when i press my mod4, and it shows no KeyPress or KeyRelease event. yet i can resize the xev window by holding down mod4, right clicking the titlebar, and then moving the mouse.  xev does not output a KeyPress event when I do this.

Comment: it seems there are lot of problems with keyboard and independently with awesome. solutions provided seems to be unmaintained. my advice,  change your keyboard or try your luck with https://gnome15.org

Comment: ok, well, easy enough. I've got about 4 keyboards from different manufacturers/models. Your comment seems kind of vague, but I'm gonna take it as a troubleshooting suggestion and will follow up with the results.

Thanks for the tip on gnome15. I can probably find that useful, but it seems like it mostly enables the enhanced features. I may go ahead with that too, but usually avoid adding unnecessary software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aklmie helped me find the problem and solve it. Everything worked properly with another keyboard so I found I had accidentally enabled the "game mode" option on the G110 by using the slider switch at the top of the keyboard. After sliding it back to off, everything worked.